# Dot Net Nuke, content localization switch NodeSelector for menu in Fr-fr

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, ascx

I've been searching for information on DotNetNuke's content localization in version 6.2.4 but I can't find much.

I have a custom DDR (DNN) Menu where I need to switch the NodeSelector in French:

For the English page it looks like this:

```
<dnn:MENU MenuStyle="LeftSideBarMenu" runat="server" NodeSelector="[Page Name in English]"></dnn:MENU>
```

When I'm on the French page, is there a way to detect the French page text and change where it says [Page Name in English] to the corresponding French Name?

Edit:

Something like:

```
<dnn:MENU MenuStyle="LeftSideBarMenu" runat="server" NodeSelector="<% if it's the English page show ENGLISH name else show FRENCH name %>"></dnn:MENU>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can update the Page settings for the French name, when you're in that mode

Comment: Like you mean give the French Page the same name as the English page?

Comment: No, if you are on the English page, click the French flag, then provide a translated name for the page

Comment: Oh I see, the Page Name is different from the page title so it won't be displayed.

Comment: But wait, I need the Node Selector to be different on the French page, if the Page name is different (which it will be since it's in a different language)...how do I switch that dynamically in the menu tag?